# How should I overwinter Kaffir Lime indoors?

Tags: citrus, overwintering

This spring I bought a small kaffir lime plant (too small to call it a tree yet) for future use of the leaves in the kitchen.

It spent a happy summer in his pot outside, but now winter is approaching and it needs to be moved indoors.

We have literally decades of experience with a common lemon tree, but that specimen is so large, old and hardened off, it lives outside unless night temperature threatens to drop below -4°C (25°F). I don't trust the kaffir baby to be this resilient yet, so it has to come inside soon.

I will provide the brightest, yet coolest spot available, possibly supply additional lighting, water carefully and generally keep an eye on it in case it brought any pests inside that escaped close examination. It will be moved outside whenever weather permits - especially during frost-free periods.

Question:
Are there any special requirements for a Kaffir Lime that are different from a regular lime? What would be a reasonable temperature threshold, given the fact that it is only about a foot high and still in a smallish pot? I know that mature lemon trees in Italy occasionally get snowed upon and so did ours without any ill effects.

To give you an idea about size:

[image: Kaffir Lime]

Comment: For what it is worth, our lime trees appear to be about the same size and age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a key lime that I am overwintering for the second year this winter. Our winters are consistently below freezing for months straight, so there is no question of keeping it outside. I keep it in a south-facing window and water it once a week during the winter. Our house is kept at 68F during the day and 62F at night. It does beautifully under these conditions, and I would expect a kaffir lime would do as well.